# NoSuchFieldError exception for new JSONArray but only in obfuscated builds

Tags: android, json

I am seeing a very strange app crash for builds I create that are obfuscated with R8 and some pro guard rules.
The code compiles and runs just fine on debug builds which are not obfuscated. It compiles but crashes for obfuscated builds.

The exact error is this:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field myArrayList of type Ljava/util/ArrayList; in class Lorg/json/JSONArray; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.json.JSONArray' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

From what I can tell, the offending line of code is this:

`JSONArray array = new JSONArray();`

It seems like obfuscated builds try to reference the org.json version of JSONArray class rather than the version provided by Android SDK - but why would that be??
This code also used to work but as far as I can tell, the only changes are version bump for android gradle plugin.

We know of 1 solution to the problem - add pro guard rules to not obfuscate the org.json classes but this seems like a work around to the actual issue

Any tips or ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As with many of my Stack Overflow questions, as soon as I post a question I figure it out!

The issue was that recently we bumped up a lib version. That new version introduced a new dependency on org.json directly.
I found the new dependency looking through the app dependencies list. As soon as I removed that org.json dependency using exclude in my gradle files, the issue was solved - no more crash, no more confusion for android as to which version of JSONArray to reference - android SDK version or org.json

`exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'` was the magic needed